# how to update WordPress role capability value

Tags: database, wordpress

How do I update WordPress user role capability value through the database? i want to add custom capability like as post_limit, then update those post limit value

Below is a screenshot showing the `wp_user_roles` options;

[image: screenshot]
`wp_user_roles => value (i want to update this unserialized value)`

Note: i want to update existing capability value not add_role or remove_role

Answer (score 1):

You can create new roles using the command [add_role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role).

```
add_role( 'custom_role', 'Custom Subscriber', array( 'read' => true, 'level_0' => true ) );
```

To modify an existing role you would need to remove it first and then add it back in.

```
 remove_role( 'custom_role' );
 add_role( 'custom_role', 'Custom Subscriber', array( 'read' => true, 'level_0' => true ) );
```

*Be aware that modifying the capabilities array and re-executing add_role() will not necessarily update the role with the new capabilities list. The add_role() function short-circuits if the role already exists in the database.*

Comment: Sorry, i want to update existing role value, not create add_role or remove_role

Comment: @TusharImran That's how you update an existing role, you need to remove it and then add it back in.  There is no update command.  You can read about it in the link I provided in my answer => "If you are defining a custom role, and adding capabilities to the role using add_role(), be aware that modifying the capabilities array and re-executing add_role() will not necessarily update the role with the new capabilities list. The add_role() function short-circuits if the role already exists in the database."

Comment: actually i want to add post limit capability and then update those capability value

Comment: @TusharImran you need to delete the role then add it back in for the changes to be made with the new capabilities.  What capability are you trying to add?  There is no capability called post limit.

Comment: i want to add custom post limit capability and then update those capability value, not pre defined capability. you can see this link http://shinephp.com/how-to-change-wordpress-user-role-capabilities/

Thank You

Comment: @TusharImran you really need to update your question, it makes it hard for people to help if you keep changing your requirements.